# Impact on Flink-SQL application using LZ4 Compression with Rocksdb state backend

Tags: apache-flink, streaming, flink-sql, rocksdb

I am using **flink 1.17.1** and running flink-sql application something like

```
create table enrich_table (
col1 STRING,
col2....
)
WITH ( 'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
    'topic' = 'enrich_table',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '${KAFKA_BROKERS}',
    'properties.group.id' = '${CONSUMER_GROUP_ID}',
    'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',
    'value.avro-confluent.url' = '${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}',
    'key.format' = 'avro-confluent',
    'key.avro-confluent.url' = '${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}');


Insert into enrich_table as 
select
    col1,col2...

from 
    table1 t1 
    inner join table2 t2 on ..
    inner join table3 t2 on ...
    .....
```

Setting LZ4 compression to rocksdb by creating custom factory

```
package my.org.abc

import org.rocksdb.{ColumnFamilyOptions, DBOptions}
import org.apache.flink.configuration.ReadableConfig
import org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.{ConfigurableRocksDBOptionsFactory, DefaultConfigurableOptionsFactory, RocksDBOptionsFactory}


import org.apache.flink.configuration.ConfigOptions
import org.apache.flink.configuration.ConfigOption

import org.apache.flink.configuration.description.LinkElement.link
import org.rocksdb.CompressionType
import org.apache.flink.configuration.description.Description


class RocksDBTuningJobOptionsFactory extends ConfigurableRocksDBOptionsFactory {
  private val defaultFactory = new DefaultConfigurableOptionsFactory
  private var configuration: ReadableConfig = _
  private val COMPRESSION: ConfigOption[CompressionType] =
    ConfigOptions.key("state.backend.rocksdb.custom.compression")
      .enumType(classOf[CompressionType])
      .noDefaultValue()
      .withDescription(
        Description.builder()
          .text("Configures RocksDB compression")
          .linebreak()
          .text(
            "For more information, please refer to %s",
            link("https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Compression")
          )
          .build()
      )

  override def configure(configuration: ReadableConfig): RocksDBOptionsFactory = {
    defaultFactory.configure(configuration)
    this.configuration = configuration
    this
  }

  override def createDBOptions(currentOptions: DBOptions, handlesToClose: java.util.Collection[AutoCloseable]): DBOptions = {
    defaultFactory.createDBOptions(currentOptions, handlesToClose)
  }

  override def createColumnOptions(currentOptions: ColumnFamilyOptions, handlesToClose: java.util.Collection[AutoCloseable]): ColumnFamilyOptions = {
    var updatedOptions = defaultFactory.createColumnOptions(currentOptions, handlesToClose)

    configuration.getOptional(COMPRESSION).ifPresent(currentOptions.setCompressionType)
    updatedOptions
  }
}
```

and providing following configuration

```
........
state.backend.rocksdb.use-bloom-filter: "true"
state.backend.rocksdb.options-factory: 'com.mdsol.streaming.util.RocksDBTuningJobOptionsFactory'
state.backend.rocksdb.custom.compression: "LZ4_COMPRESSION"
```

Q#1: As per discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537111/how-do-i-decide-between-lz4-and-snappy-compression), LZ4 improves the performance. Just wondering what is that community uses for large state, high volume and velocity flink-sql(without temporal join) based application?

Q#2: In order to set Lz4 compression, Do we have to extends ConfigurableRocksDBOptionsFactory  or is there any better way ?

Q#3: Is there any impact of changing the compression(Lz4) to existing job that is already running and have checkpoints

Answer (score 0):

From the Speedb Hive:

Q1 the default compression is Snappy.
Q2 Flink question.
Q3 RocksDB and Speedb allow changing compression type at any time. If Flink does not support this we at speedb created a backdoor to change any mutable option while running.

You can find the Speedb hive [here](https://discord.gg/72MRDXYTV8) and (once you've registered) the link to the thread with your question [here](https://discord.com/channels/1001437353312796782/1184424699925639250), if you have more questions or need additional info

Comment: Thanks Dan. About Q1, are you saying snappy that is default compression is what speedb suggest for large/infinite state flink-sql use case?